# Save json api output in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api

I am using `Net::HTTP` to get data out of a JSON API, and want to save the response given by the API in my database.

An example response is:

```
{
    "id": 1234,
    "applicationname": "test12347127834",
    "publish_key": "79123798d7981728397dddasetr7912",
    "streamname": "xxnamexx",
    "ingest": "rtmp://master.cdn.com/SSDEL1"
}
```

I want to save the `id`, `applicationname`, `publishkey` and `streamname`.

I have absolutely no clue how that could work. I would highly appreciate if someone could give me a hint, tips or examples.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Does your database have a table for these data?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches I see. One is simply to save your JSON as text. If you won't be doing a lot of post-processing of this attribute, that might do the job.

The second approach is to use :serialize on the column and Rails 3 will magically handle the back-and-forth interpolation for you. You'll be able to do

```
some_object.response.id
```

To do that simple do:

```
class YourClass
  serialize :response
```

Comment: Saving the JSON in serialized form is of limited use. Searching inside the saved string is costly compared to breaking the values out and storing them into their own fields so they can be indexed and rapidly scanned.